# how to parse an associative array through json in javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, multidimensional-array

I have a 2-D php array which i am encoding through JSON. My 2d array in php is something like this:

```
$array['A'][12] = 8;
$array['A'][8] = 21;

$array['B'][17] = 19;
$array['B'][9] = 12;
```

when I do `echo json_encode($array);` and alert this as Ajax xmlhttp.responsetext i get this in my alert box : `{"A":{"12":"8","8":"21"},"B":{"17":"19","9":"12"}}`

which is absolutely fine. Now i need to parse it in javascript so i used the JSON.parse() function. The problem is when i access the A and B fields of the string. I get this in my alert boxes: `Object object`. How to parse this associative array? I am a beginner in AJAX and JSON so please help.

Comment: B is an object as well as A, you'll need to write response.A["12"] to get "8"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var array = JSON.parse(yourResponseData);

array.A // Object
array.A['12'] //8
```

You can't access the key '12' via the dot syntax becase no variable name can start with a number.

Comment: but when i do this `var parsedJSON = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText);
alert(parsedJSON.A[8]);` i get 'undefined' in alert box :(

Comment: Use quotes or it will be consider as the eighth element: alert(parsedJSON.A["8"]);

Comment: is there a way through which i can store all the keys of the object A and object B in 2 different variables ?

Comment: You mean like var a = array.A, b = array.B; ??? Or just the keys? Try for(key in array.A){console.log(array.A[key]);}

Comment: I mean i want to store all the keys of object A (namely 12 and 8) in a variable

Answer (score 0):

You can use console.log() rather than alert() to see the complete structure of that parsed json object. 
You can easily retrieve the value by using . notation or [] brackets:
For example:

```
var returned = JSON.parse(tran.responseText);
console.log(returned['A']['8']); //which should give you '21' based on your case
```